# Doctrine Symfony

Tags: mysql, symfony, join, doctrine

Hello I am using doctrine with symfony I want to make this join

```
$select ="SELECT c.sku, t.title, p.stock FROM BackendBundle:CartItems c 
                LEFT JOIN BackendBundle:PartInfo p ON p.nkrCode= c.sku
                LEFT JOIN BackendBundle:PartInfoTitles t ON t.internalCode = c.sku
                WHERE c.cart=".$cart;
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $query = $em->createQuery($select);
                $part = $query->getResult();
```

the problem is that c.cart is an object because it has a foreign key how can I get this using doctrine?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$select ="SELECT c.sku, t.title, p.stock FROM BackendBundle:CartItems c 
                LEFT JOIN BackendBundle:PartInfo p ON p.nkrCode= c.sku
                LEFT JOIN BackendBundle:PartInfoTitles t ON t.internalCode = c.sku
                WHERE c.cart= :cart";
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $query = $em->createQuery($select)->setParameter('cart',$cart->getId());
                $part = $query->getResult();
```